# React functional: Cannot read properties of undefined, API. Acess to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

a little help I'm new in React

Why the `useEffectworks` fine, but the
`data.name`
render fines, but the e.g
`data.main.lat`
he dont have acess to, even with map.
The data in the child he can't  get it

I hope this question make sense

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from "axios";
const API_KEY = ''
function Home() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const location = useLocation();

    let val = location.pathname.slice(1)
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${val}&appid=${API_KEY}`)
            .then((response) => {
                // console.log(response);
                setData(response.data)
            }).catch((error) => {
                // console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
                // setError(error);
            });
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Home</h2>
            <p>{data.name}</p>
            {
                data.main.map((i) => {
                    <h1>{i.lat}</h1>
                })
            }
        </div>


    );
};
```

response

```
{
base: "stations"
clouds:
all: 0
[[Prototype]]: Object
cod: 200
coord: {lon: 2.3488, lat: 48.8534}
dt: 1646247623
id: 2988507
main:
feels_like: 281.92
humidity: 65
pressure: 1019
temp: 282.42
temp_max: 283.03
temp_min: 281.41
[[Prototype]]: Object
name: "Paris"
sys:
country: "FR"
id: 6550
sunrise: 1646202672
sunset: 1646242483
type: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object
timezone: 3600
visibility: 10000
weather: Array(1)
0: {id: 800, main: 'Clear', description: 'clear sky', icon: '01n'}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
wind:
deg: 100
speed: 1.54
```

How i have access to `<p> {data.coord.lat}</p>`  in the return. this shows error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')`

Comment: `data` is initialized as an array, but then it's used as an object?

Answer (score 1):

When your component first renders, `data` is an empty array. Since arrays don't have a `main` property, you'll get an error because you're trying to use a `map` function of `undefined`.

What you can do is

```js
{
                data?.main?.map((i) => (
                    <h1>{i.lat}</h1>
                ))
}
```

Which will only call the `map` function if `data.main` exists. Also, make sure that `data.main` in your response is an array as well, otherwise `map` won't work

Comment: Ok, is not and array is a JSON inside. BUT if do
 ``` data?.weather?.map((i) => {
                    console.log(i.description);
                    <p>{i.description}</p>
                })
```
The ```console.log()``` works but the ```<p>``` does  not show

Comment: @HugTheCode Try this `data?.weather?.map((i) => ( <p>{i.description}</p> ))`

Comment: Right, I edited my answer. What happened is you didn't return the `h1` element you defined. Now it should show.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check `data.main.length`

```
{
         data.main && data.main.map((i) => {
                <h1>{i.lat}</h1>
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning `<h1>{i.lat}</h1>` in the callback to `data.main.map()` method.

Either add a `return` statement:

```
data.main.map((i) => {
    return <h1>{i.lat}</h1>
})
```

Alternatively remove the curly brackets to implicitly return:

```
data.main.map((i) => <h1>{i.lat}</h1>)
```

See [`Array.map` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Ok an array we can map, and if is a JSON. 
I edit the question

Answer (score 0):

1. According to open weather API doc main you're trying to map is an object, not an array.

[image: https://openweathermap.org/current#name]

Instead of map simply access it as an object : `<p>{data.coord.lat}</p>`

2. lat element exist in coord not main object.

3.API call take some time to provide data and you're mapping state which is still empty when there's no response from API maybe you can add loading state when you're waiting response.

**Live Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-engelbart-gxzqcd?file=/src/App.js